# How to make clustered heatmap of a large dataset look nicer?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a distance matrix which I normalized, trimmed the row and column headers with python regular expressions and tried to make a clustered heatmap from it with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.read_csv('distance_matrix_Mult_Align(distance).csv', index_col=0)

row_sums = df.sum(axis=1)
new_matrix = df / row_sums[:, np.newaxis]

def acc_id(s):
    import re
    match = re.search('\|(.*)\|', s)    
    if match:
        return match.group(1)

sns.clustermap(new_matrix.rename(columns=acc_id, index=acc_id), 
               row_cluster=False,
               xticklabels=True, 
               yticklabels=True, 
               cmap='RdBu',
               center=0,
               vmin=0, 
               vmax=1)

plt.figure()
plt.show
```

My clustered map look like this:[image]
I have tried to read the documentations of clustermap and pyplot: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure
But I can not seem to understand how to make the plot look something useful. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the `acc_id` function returning?
Also, you have set both `columns` and `index` to `acc_id`, which is the name of a function. Did you forget to call the function maybe?

Comment: Hi @SamarthBhatia, `acc_id` just returns a trimmed version of the column and row headers. e.g. one column header looks like this: `sp|Q9BYW2|SETD2_HUMAN Histone-lysine N-methyltransferase SETD2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SETD2 PE=1 SV=3` After applying `acc_id`, it looks like this: `Q9BYW2`

Comment: I don't think you should share the dataset if it's not a public one, just use a minimal subset of it to represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `vmax = 1` argument. If you look at the maximum value in the whole dataset using `new_matrix.max().max()` , it is about 0.17.
So, just removing vmax as:[image: works like this] or just set a lower value for vmax